# Passing variable to ComboBox method

Tags: vb.net, variables, methods, combobox

I have a variable that is being passed from my first form, to my second form.  However, when I try to use this variable inside my ComboBox event handler method, it's showing up blank and I can't figure out why.

```
Public CellValue As String

Public Sub New(ByVal CellValue As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    MsgBox(CellValue) 
End Sub
```

This works just fine, I am able to bring up the messagebox with the Cell Value.  However, when I try to access this CellValue in my combo box method that is on the same Form, the variable is blank, and I can't figure out why.

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MsgBox(CellValue)
End Sub
```

I've tried putting the "ByVal CellValue As String" as an argument in the combobox but that does not work, I get an error that it can not handle the event.

I have the variable set as public so I don't understand what is going on.  Any help in the right direction would be great because I have been searching the net for hours.

Here is the Form1 if that helps:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim value As String

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=0.0.0.0;
                                  userid=username;
                                  password=******;
                                  database=password"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select CaseNumber, FirstName, LastName from customer"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim CellValue As Object = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value

        If IsDBNull(value) Then
            MsgBox("No Case Number for this particular record.")
        Else

            Dim ThirdForm As New Form2(CellValue)
            Me.Hide()
            ThirdForm.Show()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You arent saving the CellValue passed to that variable.  The fact that they have the same name wont automatically make the assignment, in fact it will make your code more confusing.  BTW, `Public` has nothing to do with it - that makes that variable accessible outside the form.  `Me.CellValue = CellValue`

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.  I still don't understand why it wouldn't be set if the variable works at the top of the form...  But I will keep this is mind.  Thank you.

Comment: As I said, the `CellValue` variable at the top **is a different variable** than the one passed.  They have very different scopes: the Public one has form level scope, the other one exists only in `Sub New`.  That you gave them the same name doesnt make them the same variable.  It would be better (and clearer) if you gave them different names as Lars shows

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me thanks to Plutonix in comment section.  Thank you.

```
 Me.CellValue = CellValue
```